# How do I write CV formula in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, formula, ssrs-expression

```
 =StDev(fields!Maylist)/Avg(fields!Maylist) * 100
```

I am trying to write CV formula for my report. How can i let that formula work? I am getting error sign when i run the report. Also I would like to add that formula front of formula above `IIF(IsNothing(Avg(Value)), "",` . How can I correctly write expression for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   = Iif(ISNothing(Avg(fields!Maylist.value)),0
    , StDev(fields!Maylist.value)/
    Avg(fields!Maylist.value)) *100
```

It worked with that formula

Comment: This was flagged as a low quality post review queue. Please add some description so the readers could understand. This might be deleted by the community soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=StDev(fields!Maylist.Value)/
Iif(
IsNothing(Avg(fields!Maylist.Value))
,1
,Avg(fields!Maylist.Value)) * 100
```